# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Can't create database 'sharetribe_development' (errno: 2)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hello I'm setting up a rails 3.2.21 project in MAC OS X Yosemite. while running the command `rake db:create` I got the following error

> rake aborted!
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Can't create database 'sharetribe_development' (errno: 2): CREATE DATABASE `sharetribe_development` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`

I don't know why I'm getting this error.I can access mysql using `mysql -u root` 
and here is my database.yml

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: sharetribe_development
    encoding: utf8
    username: root
    password:
    host: localhost
```

I got stucked with this thing whole day.Any suggestion will be appreciated

#### EDIT 1

in mysql, I've following databases

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### EDIT 2

I added gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20' on gem file.I'm using rails 3.2.21.I got another problem. I reinstalled mysql. after installation, I can successfully access mysql using `mysql -u root` but after the execution of command `rake db:create` it throws following error.

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). 
>   Please provide the root password for your mysql installation

after this on trying to access mysql I can't access it.It says  **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**

I didn't set any password for mysql.but I'm unable to access it.

Comment: please add snippet of `Gemfile.lock` showing gem versions of `mysql`,  `activerecord`,`rails`, etc

Comment: @illusionist please see my latest update

Comment: looks like you have set password for your database however your app is trying to access without password..

Comment: No I didn't have any password. Before running `rake db:create` I can access mysql but after this It throws the above error

Comment: I remember I have also faced same issue few days back.. issue was related to gem version conflict between `activerecord` and `mysql2`; `activerecord` version varies for version of `Rails`.. I think you should focus on `version compatibility` for the former issue you reported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version on the mysql2 gem are you using?

There is an issue with the [latest version](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21544) and you may want to fallback to 0.3.20 and see if this makes any difference.

To do this, add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
```

Delete the current gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` from the command line.

Comment: I've following version of mysql gem 

1. mysql2-0.3.14
 2. mysql2-0.3.16
 3. mysql2-0.3.18

Answer (score 1):

Add gem 'mysql2' into your Gemfile.

Comment: Did you try gem 'mysql2', '~>  0.3.13' ?

Comment: @BibekSharma: mysql2-0.4 versions do not work with current ActivereRecord, because mysql2 does not use semantic versioning, it just got broke for everyone because of that.

Comment: Try                                                                                                             $sudo ./mysql.server stop
$sudo ./mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
$ mysql
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE') WHERE user = 'root';
mysql> exit;
$sudo ./mysql.server stop
$sudo ./mysql.server start                                                                                                           Then give the password in  config/database.yml